# How to read text files into matlab and plot?

Tags: matlab

I have multiple files such as the following, which I need to run a loop over to read and plot:

```
WC-02 18507.0 1115851.0 1092068.3  4239.94 Fault_interpretation_22    1 WC-02
WC-02 18451.0 1114476.0 1091761.0  5012.56 Fault_interpretation_22    1 WC-02
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your question, it is not clear at all !

Comment: Please put 4 space before each line of the file, so it is marked as code. Then, the title is only a short summary. The real question should be in the question field (where you have the file content now..). Please include how your files are called, and the code you have now. Where *exactly* are you stuck? Reading one file? Plotting? Looping over all?

Comment: I've re-formatted the question for you, so that it's at least readable... But as @hbaderts suggests, we're going to need more information to actually answer it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textscan`

http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html

You need to know how many columns are in each line and which type are each of them (string, float, integer...)

From the documentation you can see an example similar to yours:

Content of the file:

```
09/12/2005 Level1 12.34 45 1.23e10 inf Nan Yes 5.1+3i
10/12/2005 Level2 23.54 60 9e19 -inf  0.001 No 2.2-.5i
11/12/2005 Level3 34.90 12 2e5   10  100   No 3.1+.1i
```

Code:

```
fileID = fopen('scan1.dat');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %f32 %d8 %u %f %f %s %f');
fclose(fileID);
celldisp(C)
```

PD: Textscan reads the entire file, not line by line. However you can access the desired line using cell indexing:

```
C{3}    % content of the third line
```